# How to delete row from TableView properly

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm using Qt 5.15.0 on Manjaro.

I have a table I created with TableView in qml.

I can delete a row with right click on the Id field like this:

[image: 26ef30f3-b7bd-4a36-ba99-2878044a9f42-image.png]

The deletion etc works but I get these errors in qml:

[image: 52ce968c-c472-43ea-9998-be023b617333-image.png]

The method for delete rows looks like this in `main.qml`:

```
function deleteRowFromDatabase(row) {
       console.log("before" + model.countOfRows())

       if (!model.removeEntry(row)) {
           console.log(qsTr("remove row %1 failed").arg(row))
       }

       model = QuestionsProxyModel
       console.log("after" + model.countOfRows())
   }
```

The error point to the delegate row of id in `main.qml`

```
        DelegateChoice {
            column: 0
            delegate: QuestionIdDelegate {
                id: questionIdDelegate
                width: tableView.columnWidthProvider(column)
                text: model.id                    /// this is undefined
                row: model.row

                Component.onCompleted: {
                    questionIdDelegate.markForDelete.connect(
                                tableView.deleteRowFromDatabase)
                }
            }
        }
```

Removing of the rows is implemented from C++ In a class derrived from `QIdentityProxyModel` in `questionsproxmodel.h`:

```
bool QuestionsProxyModel::removeEntry(int row)
{
    return removeRows(row, 1);
}
```

This model takes a class  `QuestionSqlTableModel` derrived from `QSqlTableModel` as a source model

The remove rows is implemented like this in `questionssqltablemodel.qml`:

```
     bool QuestionSqlTableModel::removeRows(int row, int count,
                                               const QModelIndex &parent)
        {
            auto result = QSqlTableModel::removeRows(row, count, parent);
            if (result) {
                select(); // row is not deleted from sql database until select is called
            }
        
            return result;
        }
```

From my understanding the countOfRows of the model gets updated only after the `select()` is called so I assume between `QSqlTableModel::removeRows` and `select` the TableView reads one more time with the non existing row and causes these errors in QML. How can that be prevented?

Full Source code to try it out:

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQuickStyle>

#include <QFile>
#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QSqlQuery>

#include <QSqlError>

#include "questionsproxymodel.h"
#include "questionsqltablemodel.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QUrl dbUrl{"file:///home/sandro/Desktop/test.db"};
    auto exists = QFile::exists(dbUrl.toLocalFile());

    auto db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE", "DBConnection");
    db.setDatabaseName(dbUrl.toLocalFile());
    db.open();

    if (!exists) {
        const QString questionTableName = "questions";
        QSqlQuery query{db};
        query.exec("CREATE TABLE " + questionTableName +
                   " ("
                   "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT)");
    }

    QScopedPointer<QuestionSqlTableModel> questionSqlTableModel(
        new QuestionSqlTableModel(nullptr, db));

    QScopedPointer<QuestionsProxyModel> questionsProxyModel{
        new QuestionsProxyModel};
    questionsProxyModel->setSourceModel(questionSqlTableModel.get());

    if (!exists) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            questionsProxyModel->addNewEntry();
        }
    }

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    qmlRegisterSingletonInstance<QuestionsProxyModel>(
        "QuestionsProxyModels", 1, 0, "QuestionsProxyModel",
        questionsProxyModel.get());

    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/qml/main.qml"));
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

**questionssqltablemodel.h**

```
#include <QSqlTableModel>

class QuestionSqlTableModel : public QSqlTableModel {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit QuestionSqlTableModel(QObject *parent = nullptr,
                                   const QSqlDatabase &db = QSqlDatabase());

    bool removeRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent) override;
};
```

**questionssqltablemodel.cpp**

```
#include "questionsqltablemodel.h"

#include <QBuffer>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QPixmap>

#include <QSqlError>
#include <QSqlField>
#include <QSqlRecord>
#include <QSqlRelationalDelegate>

QuestionSqlTableModel::QuestionSqlTableModel(QObject *parent,
                                             const QSqlDatabase &db)
    : QSqlTableModel{parent, db}
{
    setTable("questions");
    setSort(0, Qt::AscendingOrder);
    if (!select()) {
        qDebug() << "QuestionSqlTableModel: Select table questions failed";
    }
    setEditStrategy(EditStrategy::OnFieldChange);
}

bool QuestionSqlTableModel::removeRows(int row, int count,
                                       const QModelIndex &parent)
{
    auto result = QSqlTableModel::removeRows(row, count, parent);
    if (result) {
        select(); // row is not deleted from sql database until select is called
    }

    return result;
}
```

**questionsproxymodel.h:**

```
#include <QIdentityProxyModel>
#include <QObject>

class QuestionsProxyModel : public QIdentityProxyModel {
    Q_OBJECT

    enum questionRoles {
        idRole = Qt::UserRole + 1,
    };

public:
    QuestionsProxyModel(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const override;

    Q_INVOKABLE QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index,
                              int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;

    bool setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value,
                 int role = Qt::EditRole) override;

    bool addNewEntry();
    Q_INVOKABLE bool removeEntry(int row);
    Q_INVOKABLE int countOfRows() const;

private:
    QModelIndex mapIndex(const QModelIndex &source, int role) const;
};
```

**questionsproxymodel.h:**

```
#include "questionsproxymodel.h"

#include <QBuffer>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QPixmap>

#include <QByteArray>

#include <QSqlError>
#include <QSqlTableModel>

QuestionsProxyModel::QuestionsProxyModel(QObject *parent)
    : QIdentityProxyModel(parent)
{
}

QHash<int, QByteArray> QuestionsProxyModel::roleNames() const
{
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
    roles[idRole] = "id";
    return roles;
}

QVariant QuestionsProxyModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    QModelIndex newIndex = mapIndex(index, role);
    if (role == idRole) {

        return QIdentityProxyModel::data(newIndex, Qt::DisplayRole);
    }
    return QIdentityProxyModel::data(newIndex, role);
}

bool QuestionsProxyModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index,
                                  const QVariant &value, int role)
{
    QModelIndex newIndex = mapIndex(index, role);

    if (role == idRole) {

        return QIdentityProxyModel::setData(newIndex, value, Qt::EditRole);
    }
    return QIdentityProxyModel::setData(newIndex, value, role);
}

bool QuestionsProxyModel::addNewEntry()
{
    auto newRow = rowCount();

    if (!insertRows(newRow, 1)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!setData(createIndex(newRow, 0), newRow + 1)) {
        removeRows(newRow, 1);
        return false;
    }
    auto sqlModel = qobject_cast<QSqlTableModel *>(sourceModel());
    return sqlModel->submit();
}

bool QuestionsProxyModel::removeEntry(int row)
{
    return removeRows(row, 1);
}

int QuestionsProxyModel::countOfRows() const
{
    return rowCount();
}

QModelIndex QuestionsProxyModel::mapIndex(const QModelIndex &source,
                                          int role) const
{
    switch (role) {
    case idRole:
        return createIndex(source.row(), 0);
    }
    return source;
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import Qt.labs.qmlmodels 1.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.15

import QuestionsProxyModels 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 1460
    height: 800

    TableView {
        id: tableView
        width: parent.width

        anchors.fill: parent
        boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds

        reuseItems: true
        clip: true
        property var columnWidths: [60]
        columnWidthProvider: function (column) {
            return columnWidths[column]
        }

        model: QuestionsProxyModel

        delegate: DelegateChooser {
            id: chooser

            DelegateChoice {
                column: 0
                delegate: QuestionIdDelegate {
                    id: questionIdDelegate
                    width: tableView.columnWidthProvider(column)
                    text: model.id
                    row: model.row

                    Component.onCompleted: {
                        questionIdDelegate.markForDelete.connect(
                                    tableView.deleteRowFromDatabase)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {}

        function deleteRowFromDatabase(row) {
            console.log("before" + model.countOfRows())

            if (!model.removeEntry(row)) {
                console.log(qsTr("remove row %1 failed").arg(row))
            }

            model = QuestionsProxyModel
            console.log("after" + model.countOfRows())
        }
    }
}
```

**QuestionIdDelegate.qml:**

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

TextField {
    property int row

    signal markForDelete(int row)

    id: root

    implicitHeight: 100

    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter

    readOnly: true

    background: Frame {}

    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        acceptedButtons: Qt.RightButton

        onClicked: {
            eraseContextMenu.popup(root, 0, mouseArea.mouseY + 10)
        }
    }

    Menu {
        id: eraseContextMenu
        y: root.y
        MenuItem {
            text: qsTr("Delete entry")
            onTriggered: {
                eraseDialog.open()
                eraseContextMenu.close()
            }
        }
        MenuItem {
            text: qsTr("Cancel")
            onTriggered: {
                eraseContextMenu.close()
            }
        }
    }

    Dialog {
        id: eraseDialog
        title: qsTr("Delete database entry")
        modal: true
        focus: true

        contentItem: Label {
            id: label
            text: qsTr("Do you really want to erase the entry with id %1?").arg(
                      root.text)
        }

        onAccepted: {
            markForDelete(root.row)
        }

        standardButtons: Dialog.Ok | Dialog.Cancel
    }
}
```

**.pro:**

```
QT += quick
QT += quickcontrols2
QT += sql

CONFIG += c++17

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

HEADERS += \
    questionsproxymodel.h \
    questionsqltablemodel.h

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        questionsproxymodel.cpp \
        questionsqltablemodel.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules just for Qt Quick Designer
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

edit:

The answer solves the error stated above. However I detected another problem with the code.

If I delete the row 1 and then the row 2 my output looks like this:
[image]

This binding loop error points `Dialog` in `QuestionsIDDelegate`:

```
Dialog {
    id: eraseDialog
    title: qsTr("Delete database entry")
    modal: true
    focus: true

    contentItem: Label {
        id: label
        text: qsTr("Do you really want to erase the entry with id %1?").arg(
                  root.text)
    }

    onAccepted: {
        markForDelete(root.row)
    }

    standardButtons: Dialog.Ok | Dialog.Cancel
}
```

Comment: I shortened it down to minimal example. its still a bit bulky because of the sql background

Comment: You're using a role name of `id`. I don't know for sure if that actually causes a problem in your app, but at the very least, I consider it unsafe because it's a built-in QML property. I'd be curious to know if you get any better results simply changing the name?

Comment: its a good point. I think I will rename that column. However in my real application I have more columns which are not named id with the same assign error happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to prevent this is to check that the property is not undefined:

```
text: model.id === undefined ? "" : model.id
```

Comment: Thanks alot that solves the error indeed. Can you also have a look at the binding loop error. Which also shows up with the code? Also does the behavior mean that the QML TableView and the model are like out of sync for a moment?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to fix the code, but I am going to try to explain *why* you are having trouble. I feel the why of things will help more people.

[image]

This image may not be 100% accurate but it is how one must visualize things in their mind. You have three distinct lanes an object lives in when you introduce QML: C++, QML Engine, and JavaScript engine. Each and every one of those lanes believes beyond a shadow of a doubt that **they control the life and death of the object**.

When you are just passing integers around that are passed by value, this is no issue. When you are passing QStrings around, because of the copy-on-write charter of Qt, this is only a minor issue. When you are passing real objects around, worse yet, complex containers of real objects, you have to understand this completely. The answer that "fixed" your problem really only masked it. You will find there is a lot of QML and JavaScript code out there that exists only to mask an application not respecting the lanes.

Had this application used an actual database there would be a fourth lane. Yes, SQLite provides an SQL interface and allows many things, but an actual database has an external engine providing shared access and controlling the life of cursors. SQLite files tend to be single user. Yes, multiple threads within your application can access it, but while your application is running you cannot open a terminal window and use command line tools to examine the database. Think of it more as a really nice indexed file system without sharing.

So, you create an object in C++ and then expose it to QML. The QML engine now believes beyond a doubt that it controls the life and death of that object despite not having its own copy.

QML is really feeble. It can't actually do much, so it has to hand any significant object off to JavaScript. The JavaScript engine now believes beyond a shadow of a doubt that it now controls the life and death of that object.

You need to also envision these lanes as independent threads. There will most likely be many threads within each, but, in general, any signal or communication between these will go on the event loop of the target **as a queued event**. That means it will only be processed when it finally bubbles to the top of the queue for that event loop.

This, btw, **is why you can never use Smart Pointers** when also using QML/JavaScript. Especially the kind that do reference counting and delete the object when there are no more references. There is no way for the C++ lane to know that QML or JavaScript are still using the object.

The answer telling you to check for undefined property is masking the problem that your code is drunk driving across all lanes. Eventually, on a faster (or sometimes slower) processor garbage collection for one of the lanes will run at a *most* inopportune moment and you will be greeted with a stack dump. (The drunk driving code will hit a tree that does not yield.)

**Correct Solution #1:**
Never use QML or JavaScript. Just use C++ and Widgets. Stay entirely within the C++ lane. If that is a route open to you it's a good way to go. There is an awful lot of production code out there doing just that. You can obtain a copy of [this book](https://www.theminimumyouneedtoknow.com/qt_book.html) (or just download the source code from the page) and muddle through building it.

**Correct Solution #2:**
*Never actually do anything* in QML or JavaScript. This is an all together different solution than #1. You can use QML *for UI only*, leaving all logic in C++. Your code is failing because you are trying to actually do something. I haven't built or tried your code. I simply saw

```
function deleteRowFromDatabase(row)
```

which shouldn't exist at all. C++ holds your model. You emit a signal from your QML/JavaScript lanes when user action requires deletion. This signal becomes a queued event in the C++ lane. When it is processed the row will be deleted and the model updated. If you have properly exposed your model to QML it will emit some form of "model changed" signal and the UI will update accordingly. One of the main points of MVC (Model-View-Controler) is communication to/from the model. When the data changes it notifies the view(s).

**Correct Solution #3:**
Never use C++. Have your C++ be a "Hello World!" shell that just launches your QML. Never create and share an object between C++ and the other two lanes. Do everything inside of JavaScript and QML.

Binding loop errors, in general, happen when code drunk drives across all three lanes. They also happen when code doesn't view each lane as at least one distinct thread with its own event loop. The C++ lane hasn't finished (perhaps not even started) the delete operation but your code is already trying to use the result.

I don't know why, but some people edit these things and delete the correct answers. The full information was too long for SO and is contained here,

https://www.logikalsolutions.com/wordpress/uncategorized/so-you-cant-get-your-qt-models-to-work-with-qml/

with source even.

Comment: I'm aware about Solution 1. With Solution 2 you suggest I connect with a signal from QML to the model in C++. So it gets called at the right time ?

Comment: No. You cannot control the timing of anything between the lanes. That is what people who reach for QML and JavaScript don't understand. The only correct way to use it is not to use it at all. This function goes away:function deleteRowFromDatabase(row) {
            console.log("before" + model.countOfRows())

            if (!model.removeEntry(row)) {
                console.log(qsTr("remove row %1 failed").arg(row))
            }

            model = QuestionsProxyModel
            console.log("after" + model.countOfRows())
        }  You send a signal to C++ and that's it.

Comment: You are trying to actually "use" QML and JavaScript and that just can't be done. You are trying to control the order of execution in a different lane with its own thread and eventLoop. This cannot be done. Worse, the code is trying to re-use the model immediately after.You just send the signal to C++. When the model has been updated it should automatically signal the other lane data has changed. This should all go on happy happy without you ever touching model in QML/JavaScript. Worst case you have the C++ lane send a signal when it is done to force an update. Should not be needed.

Comment: Ok I think I understand. I should emit a signal from QML instead of call the erase from javascript directly, which invokes a Slot on the C++ site. This way it all gets invoked at the right time. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I tried it out even with sending a signal to the c++ site and deleting from C++ still both errors occur and I still need the fix from the other answer. I would really appreciate a solution here for the code posted.

Comment: You need to post the code where you tried doing everything in C++. If you are getting that error even then it is because you are either:  1) __still__ trying to re-assign the model   2) doing something else wrong

Comment: You didn't provide all of the code. What you did provide won't even compile. It's missing include file statements. What version of Qt are you using? I'm asking because according to this post: https://medium.com/@yuvaram.aligeti/using-singleton-class-in-qml-5ed1c934d2d5  qmlRegisterSingletonInstance isn't part of early Qt 5.x. It is definitely not part of my 5.12 install on Ubuntu 2.04 LTS. If you want people to physically debug your code you need to provide complete __ACCURATE__ code including the .PRO file. You also need to be specific about your versions. If this is 6.x you are on your own.

Comment: I added the missing pro file. I don't see were include files are missing. I copied the code complete except the Include guards in .h files.

Comment: questionsproxymodel.cpp (which is the second .h of its name) doesn't even have an #include statement for questionsproxymodel.h. Several others are missing such things. You've never stated __exactly__ which version of Qt you are using. The code you have posted here WILL NOT COMPILE on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with the version of Qt from the repos. qmlRegisterSingletonInstance does not exist in that version. There is absolutely no reason to be using a proxymodel in this. I'm done wasting time on this. You are trying to "fix code" when the problem is bad architecture.

Comment: you are right i missed to include these one. No idea why they were missing. I use Qt5.15.0 on Manjaro and there qmlRegisterSingletonInstance exists since it was introduced in Qt 5.14.